# How to find parametric equation for a curve with varying radius of curvature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, curves, parametrization

I would like to find the parametric equation for a curve starting at radius of curvature 10 at angle 0 degrees and ending at radius of curvature 100 at 90 degrees. The equation for change in radius of curvature along the path will be specified.

One can imagine this as a 90 degree arc of a circle, except the radius of the circle is changing along the path. This is similar to the concept of Euler curves, except the curvature only changes linearly for Euler curves.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Edit: Thanks for the many replies! Actually my question is that the rate of change of radius of curvature can be any function. In my case, I'd like it to be a tanh function going from radius r1 to radius r2. The radii I mentioned above are also arbitrary values.  I am looking for an analytical or numerical way to approach the generalized problem.

Comment: Perhaps it wouldn't be a bad idea to approach this in polar coordinates. The radius (of curvature) is just the coordinate $r$.And we have some curve that has the function $r=r(\theta)$. We know $r(\theta=0) = 10$ and $r(\theta=90^{\circ})=100$. Do you know anything else?

Comment: Otherwise, I don't really see what you mean. Why should the centre move? How will it move?

Comment: @2668269: Equation for change in radius of curvature along the path .. will be specified by you or by those who answer?

Comment: @user2668269: You have so far not specified change in  radius of curvature along the path.

Comment: I have added some clarification above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Matti, I realize that the line about changing the center is confusing. I was simply thinking about it in terms of the center of a circle. Anyway, I removed that line from my question for clarity.

Comment: @2668269: Why do you specify a tanh curve? The unmodified $\tanh x $ has a maximum of $45^{\circ}$ and you want  $90^{\circ}$. An Ellipse rotates even more and Cornu spiral accommodates any large rotation.

Comment: A  solution with tanh is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Natural/intrinsic differential equations need to be used. The  Whewell's equation binding tangent rotation $\phi$  and arc length $s$ is more suitable compared to Cesàro equation $(\kappa, s)$ and it can be used for a given variation of curvature thus :

$$\frac{1}{\kappa} = R= \frac{ds}{d \phi} = a \tanh (\phi) \tag1 $$

Integrate using *arbitrary* boundary  conditions ( does not matter because the entire track can be subjected to any Euclidean motion, i.e., rotation and shift in plane)  arc length $ s=0 ,\, \phi= -\frac{\pi}{4}$

$$s= a\,log\,\dfrac{\cosh \phi}{\cosh \pi/4} ;\; \cosh \phi= \cosh \pi/4 \cdot e^{s/a}\tag2 $$

and parametric coordinates

$$ x= \int \cos\phi \;ds,\,y= \int \sin\phi \;ds,\,\tag3 $$

Designated constant $a$ is obtained (by numerical solution) of two simultaneous equations for$(\phi_i, a) $
$$ R_1= a \tanh \phi_i,\; R_2= a\tanh (\phi_i+ \pi/2)\tag4 $$

Numerical integration gives the required bent curve.

EDIT1:

The unmodified $\tanh(x)$ has a maximum of $45^\circ$ against the required $90^\circ$ tangent rotation. It does not result in the required rotation, so is an unsuitable choice for specifying the curve.

An Ellipse rotates $90^\circ$  for curvature ratio $ (a/b)^3 $ in a quadrant. Also the *director circle* is the solution of perpendicular tangents in any ellipse.

Other examples can be suggested: the *Cornu spiral* and the *Involute* can accommodate any large rotation between perpendicular tangents.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple curve, the ellipse

$$\begin{cases}x&=&a \cos(t)\\ y&=&b\sin(t)\end{cases} \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \ \ \ \ $$

providing an answer to your issue. Indeed, its curvature is

$$K=\dfrac{ab}{(a^2 \sin^2 t + b^2 \cos^2 t)^{3/2}}\tag{1}$$

(see example 1 in [this reference](https://www.math24.net/curvature-radius/)), therefore with max. and min. **radii of curvature** :

$$a^2/b \ \ \text{ in} \ \  A(a,0) \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \  \ b^2/a \ \  \text{ in} \ \ B(0,b).$$

It remains to solve : $$a^2/b=10 \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \  \ b^2/a=100...$$

giving

$$a=10^{4/3} \approx 21.54  \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \  \ b=10^{5/3}\approx 46.42.$$

**Edit :** the locus of centers of curvature, called the evolute, of an ellipse is an elongated astroid : see the very nice figures [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute#Evolute_of_an_ellipse)

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for your reply. The ellipse is one curve that can go from one radius of curvature to another, but doesn't necessarily follow a given function for the rate of change of curvature.

Comment: While simple and not generalized, an ellipse does seem to have the shape of change of curvature that I wanted. I'm now taking a closer look to see if it'll apply to my problem. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Comment: I have added two things : formula (1) which answers to your question " doesn't necessarily follow a given function for the rate of change of curvature" by showing that there is an explicit formula for the curvature at any point (formula (1)) and an edit where I mention that the locus of centers of curvature is a as well a known curve called an astroid. IMHO, one can adapt in a numericl way the ellipse in order to have a change of curvature as you desire it...